# 3D convolution product with Fourier transforms, FFTW and MPI in C

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, convolution, ifft, c

My question is not really from the field of signal processing but I think you are the most suited for answering my question.

I am willing to compute the gravitational potential which can be written as the result of a convolution product:
$$\Phi(x,y,z)=\iiint G(x-x',y-y',z-z') \rho(x',y',z') dx' dy' dz' = (G * \rho)(x,y,z)$$ with $ G(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$

The algorithm I am implementing make use of the Fourier transforms and the convolution theorem which allows to compute the potential as follows:
$$\Phi(x,y,z) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{G}(k)\cdot\hat{\rho}(k))$$

I tested the algorithm with a known particular solution (see point 4.below) and the results provided are not correct.
I suspect that it is because the positions in my final result are shifted (I read few posts but I do not really understood how to solve it). Can you explain to me (in a simple way please :)), please, why I am not getting the correct result and how to solve it ? I attach my code.

Thank you in advance,
Steven

P-S:

1. The potential and density are periodic in the box. Thus I do not need to do a zero padding.
2. $x\in [-x_{len}/2,x_{len}/2]$, $y\in [-y_{len}/2,y_{len}/2]$, $z\in [-z_{len}/2,z_{len}/2]$
3. The code is not concise in purpose. I want to make it very simple to understand before optimising the writening.
4. For $\rho=\rho_0$ if $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}<r_0$, and 0 otherwise the potential should be:

$\Phi(r)=-2\pi \rho_0 (r_0^2-r^2/3)$ if $r<r_0$, and $-\frac{4\pi\rho_0 r_0^3}{3 r}$ otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <fftw3-mpi.h>
#include <string.h> // for memset
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // General variables
    ptrdiff_t i, j, k;

    // FFTW
    fftw_plan plan_r2c_density, plan_r2c_green, plan_c2r_potential;
    fftw_complex *density_real, *potential_real, *green_real;
    fftw_complex *potential_complex, *density_complex, *green_complex;
    ptrdiff_t alloc_local, local_nx, local_x_start;


    // 3D meshgrid
    const ptrdiff_t Nx = 61, Ny = 61, Nz = 61;
    double x, y, z;
    double xlen=5, ylen=5, zlen=5;
    double dx=xlen/(Nx-1), dy=ylen/(Ny-1), dz=zlen/(Nz-1);
    double xini=-xlen/2, yini=-ylen/2, zini=-zlen/2;
    double FFT_norm = 1.0/Nx/Ny/Nz;


    /* Initialise MPI */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);


    /*Initialize FFTW */
    fftw_mpi_init();

    alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_3d(Nx, Ny, Nz, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                                               &local_nx, &local_x_start);

    /* Allocation of arrays for the transform */
    density_real       = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
    potential_real     = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
    green_real         = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);

    density_complex    = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
    potential_complex  = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
    green_complex      = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);

    /* create plan for in-place forward DFT */
    plan_r2c_density   = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_3d(Nx, Ny, Nz,
                                        density_real, density_complex,
                                        MPI_COMM_WORLD, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    plan_r2c_green     = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_3d(Nx, Ny, Nz,
                                        green_real, green_complex,
                                        MPI_COMM_WORLD, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    plan_c2r_potential = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_3d(Nx, Ny, Nz,
                                        potential_complex, potential_real,
                                        MPI_COMM_WORLD, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);



    /* Density sphere test */
    double r=0, r0=0.2;
    double rho0=1;
    for (i = 0; i < local_nx; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < Ny; ++j)
        {
                for (k = 0; k < Nz; ++k)
                {
                        x = xini + (local_x_start + i)*dx;
                        y = yini + j*dy;
                        z = zini + k*dz;
                        r = sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2));

                        /* Uniform density sphere */
                        if (r<r0) {
                                density_real[k+Nz*(i*Ny + j)][0] = rho0;
                        } else {
                                density_real[k+Nz*(i*Ny + j)][0] = 0;
                        }
                        density_real[k+Nz*(i*Ny + j)][1] = 0.0;
                }
        }
    }

    /* Green's function */
    for (i = 0; i < local_nx; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < Ny; ++j)
        {
                for (k = 0; k < Nz; ++k)
                {
                        x = xini + (local_x_start + i)*dx;
                        y = yini + j*dy;
                        z = zini + k*dz;

                        if (x==0.0 && y==0.0 && z==0.0)
                        {
                                green_real[k+Nz*(i*Ny + j)][0] =
                                                      -1/sqrt( dx*dx );
                        } else {
                                green_real[k+Nz*(i*Ny + j)][0] =
                                                      -1/sqrt( x*x + y*y + z*z );
                        }
                        green_real[k+Nz*(i*Ny + j)][1] = 0.0;
                }
        }
    }


    /* Execute forward tranform for density */
    /* Must be done at each time step */
    fftw_execute(plan_r2c_density);

    /* Execute forward tranform for Green's function */
    /* Must be done only once */
    fftw_execute(plan_r2c_green);

    /* Compute the complex potential */
    for (i=0; i < local_nx; i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<Ny;j++)
        {
                for (k=0;k<Nz;k++)
                {
                    potential_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][0] =
                                 green_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][0]*density_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][0]
                               - green_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][1]*density_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][1];

                    potential_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][1] =
                                 green_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][0]*density_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][1]
                               + green_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][1]*density_complex[k+Nz*(j+Ny*i)][0];
                }
        }
    }

    /* Execute backward tranform and normalise potential */
    fftw_execute(plan_c2r_potential);

    for (i = 0; i < local_nx; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < Ny; ++j)
        {
                for (k = 0; k < Nz; ++k)
                {
                        // 1st normalisation is for FFTW
                        // 2nd normalisation is for the volume element
                        potential_real[k+Nz*(i*Ny + j)][0] = FFT_norm*FFT_norm*potential_real[k+Nz*(i*Ny + j)][0];
                }
        }
     }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I suggest using standard debugging procedures. Start with simple signals with known answers: single impulses in one dimension, add impulses, sine waves (test LTI), expand to hire dimensions, etc. Once you fail your first test case, you can single step through your code until you find the discrepancy or ask with more details here. Do NOT proceed to more complex test cases until you pass all the simpler ones.

Comment: I don't know how `fftw` works, but it looks like the chosen FFT sizes are `61`, and [there is no zero padding added.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/64519/80)  That possibly means there will be time-domain aliasing in any resulting inverse FFT.  Perhaps you can expand your question and show precisely what you mean by `The results that my algorithm is providing are not correct` ?

Comment: Your Green function doesn't look periodic.  You should add enough zero padding to ensure that your circular convolution via FFTs is in fact equivalent to linear convolution and check the results.  Saying functions are periodic is not a sound justification for implying aliasing doesn't affect your desired result.

Comment: @Hilmar You are right. I just started with a 1D example and realized that after the convolution product the position of my domain is shifted by N/2.

Comment: @PeterK. I edited my question.

Comment: @AndyWalls The Green's function is periodic in my box which is center on 0. For example, $G(x=-x_{len}/2,0,0)=G(x=x_{len}/2,0,0)$. But I agree with your comment and the previous one that I should consider adding a zero padding

Comment: @YouShallNotPass: are you aware that multiplying DFT spectra implements circular convolution, not linear convolution ? Do you understand the difference between the two ?

Comment: @Hilmar I read https://thewolfsound.com/circular-vs-linear-convolution-whats-the-difference/ and if I well understood the circular convolution is the one suited for my problem since both functions have same (spatial) period and are sampled with the same number of points

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem is two-fold:

1. **Comparison with an exact solution:**
   This convolution product is an equivalent writing of Poisson's equation in a periodic 3D box. Therefore it should fulfill same constraints. However, the Poisson's equation in a periodic box is consistent mathematically if and only if the mean value of the source term vanishes in the computational box. This was not the case for my test. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76653405/17351877 for more details.
2. **Shift in positions:**
   the positions of my final result were indeed shifted by half in all directions. This is explained by the fact that I was mixing up the center of the numerical grid (which starts with indices (0,0,0)) and the center of my 'physical' grid (which has indices $(N_x/2, N_y/2, N_z/2)$). Therefore, for avoiding this "shift of positions" it is sufficient to put the center of the Green's function at indices $(0,0,0)$.

Below is a 2D example of convolution between a Dirac and a square (I replaced the Green's function by a Dirac to recover the initial signal)

[image]